# Detect multiple black dots on paper and their relative distance while clicking photo

Tags: image-processing, camera, photo

I want multiple users to take photographs of a paper which has four dots at the four edges. While user is taking photograph, to make sure that the paper is flat and not crumpled, I want an overlaid frame to turn green, if the camera can detect four dots with the known relative distance, thus signifying the correct position of paper for photograph.

I have zero knowledge of image processing. Let me know if it is even possible, considering the camera application of both iOS and Android.

Comment: yes this is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have not put your question in clear way, still I will try to give you an answer, you can use language of your choice, I am assuming that in the frame there will be paper only, and background should be uniform.

1) Threshold your image for detection of Paper only.

2) Once you have a binary image with paper you can extract its contour information. (In opencv use `contours = cv2.findContours(thresholdimage, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`)

3) Get corner points of the contour. (In opencv you can use`cv2.approxPolyDP` and get list of the points).

From here you have multiple options, if you want to check alignment of paper is correct or not, use position of points. or you can find distance between them.

to check alignment of your rectangle you can find `arctan` between points which should be perpendicular in ideal case, you can use it as a measure.

Thank You.